# Getting information inside script function from webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get information from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Rascal and similar pages. The information that I am interested in is in the window on the right side on upper part of page that lists details of the language such as `execution method, garbage collected` etc. This information is contained in following line on the html source of the page:

```
<script type="8b5f853f8b614ed469e51514-">window.RLQ = window.RLQ || []; window.RLQ.push( function () {
mw.config.set({"wgCanonicalNamespace":"Category","wgCanonicalSpecialPageName":!1,"wgNamespaceNumber":14,"wgPageName":"Category:Rascal","wgTitle":"Rascal","wgCurRevisionId":137957,"wgRevisionId":137957,"wgArticleId":11663,"wgIsArticle":!0,"wgIsRedirect":!1,"wgAction":"view","wgUserName":null,"wgUserGroups":["*"],

"wgCategories":["Execution method/Interpreted","Garbage collection/Yes","Parameter passing/By value","Typing/Safe","Typing/Strong","Typing/Expression/Partially implicit","Typing/Checking/Dynamic","Impl needed","Programming Languages"],

"wgBreakFrames":!1,"wgPageContentLanguage":"en","wgPageContentModel":"wikitext","wgSeparatorTransformTable":["",""],"wgDigitTransformTable":["",""],"wgDefaultDateFormat":"dmy","wgMonthNames":["","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"wgMonthNamesShort":["","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],"wgRelevantPageName":"Category:Rascal"
,"wgRelevantArticleId":11663,"wgIsProbablyEditable":!0,"wgRestrictionEdit":[],"wgRestrictionMove":[],"sfgAutocompleteValues":[],"sfgAutocompleteOnAllChars":!1,"sfgFieldProperties":[],"sfgDependentFields":[],"sfgShowOnSelect":[],"sfgScriptPath":"/mw/extensions/SemanticForms","sdgDownArrowImage":"/mw/extensions/SemanticDrilldown/skins/down-arrow.png","sdgRightArrowImage":"/mw/extensions/SemanticDrilldown/skins/right-arrow.png"});mw.loader.implement("user.options",function($,jQuery){mw.user.options.set({"variant":"en"});});mw.loader.implement("user.tokens",function($,jQuery){mw.user.tokens.set({"editToken":"+\\","patrolToken":"+\\","watchToken":"+\\"});});mw.loader.load(["ext.smw.style","ext.smw.tooltips","mediawiki.page.startup","mediawiki.legacy.wikibits"]);
} );</script>
```

The main part is in `"wgCategories"` (shown in the middle of code above).

I have following code to get the page:

```
import requests, sys
lang_url = 'https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Rascal'
rg = requests.get(lang_url)
if rg is None: 
   print("Could not obtain web page.")
   sys.exit()
else: print("length of obtained page:", len(rg.text) )

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

What function of BeautifulSoup can I use to get this information?

Edit: I checked about BeautifulSoup - I can get `title`, `para` by `p` and links by `a` and `a['href']` and so on, but I cannot find a method to find and search inside a script `function`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here's the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Pl see the edit in my question above.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your `requests` object's `content` into the `BeautifulSoup` constructor, while specifying `BeautifulSoup`'s HTML parser, `html.parser`, to get it in the correct format. Then, you can use `BeautifulSoup`'s [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) function, which has an element tag parameter and returns a list. See below:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Rascal')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('script'))
```

Another option is to use `regex`, if you're into that kind of thing.

Comment: What about `soup = bs(r.text, "lxml") ` or just `soup = bs(r.text)` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not beautifulsoup, but you may want to use re for this, as html parsing will return the entire script block.

```
import re
wgcontent = re.findall('wgCategories":\[(.+?)]', rg.text)[0].replace('"', '').split(',')
```

this will return a list of:

```
Execution method/Interpreted
Garbage collection/Yes
Parameter passing/By value
Typing/Safe
Typing/Strong
Typing/Expression/Partially implicit
Typing/Checking/Dynamic
Impl needed
Programming Languages
```